# ErpNext jalali calendar

Tags: javascript, erpnext, jalali-calendar

How to add jalali clock and calendar to erpNext?
Is there a way to manually add the jalali calendar to [ErpNext](https://github.com/frappe/erpnext)?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add lines to the below file.

```
~/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/public/js/frappe/form/controls/datepicker_i18n.js
```

An example is here for the Turkish calendar:

```
;(function ($) { $.fn.datepicker.language['tr'] = {
    days: ['Pazar', 'Pazartesi', 'Salı', 'Çarşamba', 'Perşembe', 'Cuma', 'Cumartesi'],
    daysShort: ['Paz', 'Pzt', 'Sal', 'Çar', 'Per', 'Cum', 'Cmt'],
    daysMin: ['Pz', 'Pt', 'Sa', 'Ça', 'Pe', 'Cu', 'Ct'],
    months: ['Ocak','Şubat','Mart','Nisan','Mayıs','Haziran', 'Temmuz','Ağustos','Eylül','Ekim','Kasım','Aralık'],
    monthsShort: ['Oca', 'Şub', 'Mar', 'Nis', 'May', 'Haz', 'Tem', 'Ağu', 'Eyl', 'Eki', 'Kas', 'Ara'],
    today: 'Bugün',
    clear: 'Temizle',
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    timeFormat: 'hh:ii',
    firstDay: 1
};
 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Merci. Thank you for your help